# Using an eval() server side in a Python/Django application

Tags: python, django, eval

Eval is evil, rm -rf /,  etc etc...

but lets say for some silly reason I actually want to leverage the power of eval to do basic computations and conditionals.

I want to get an idea of what the potential risks are for even having an eval block sitting around in my server side code, and what I can do in order to mitigate them.

For starters, eval will actually be run against user input... even scarier I know. These are *super users*, who, in theory can be trusted, but disgruntled former employees and the like is always a thing.

The *intended* use of the input is to provide a formula used to do calculations against a spreadsheet that is parsed. So for example, an *intended* input would be something like:

```
({{Column A}} + {{Column B}}) * {{Column C}}
```

A regex engine is then run on this value to replace all curly bracket values with appropriate column values, to turn the statement into something like:

```
(5 + 6) * 11
```

However, left alone, I recognize they could do something like:

```
from subprocess import call; call(["rm", "-rf", "/"])
```

So, the idea is to come up with clean method that will allow for:
1) String values to be valid
2) Anything within brackets to be valid since it won't be eval'd
3) Nothing else containing alphanumeric characters to be valid.

What I've got so far is:

```
import re
from django import forms

def eval_template_clean(self, value, fieldname):
    # remove bracket items as they will be replaced and not evaluated
    value = re.sub("{{.*?}}", "", value)
    # remove string values as they are valid
    value = re.sub("\".*?\"", "", value)
    value = re.sub("\'.*?\'", "", value)
    # if any alpha characters remain, throw an error
    if re.search('[a-zA-Z]', value):
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            {fieldname: ['All your base are belong to us']}
        )
```

Which gets run on the model save method, disallowing any arbitrary alphanumeric commands hanging around.

Are there any flaws/other risks I'm missing with this approach?